# Difficulty with nginx rewrite syntax

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I need to extract 3 input parameters (in this example `a=test, b=sell, c=12536`) from the following URL

`/property-test-sell-12536`

and pass to the PHP file as $_GET parameters. And inside PHP file I want to access this parameter as $_GET['a'], $_GET['b'], $_GET['c'].

I researched Google about this issue. Is it possible to use only NGINX for this purpose or should I do it inside PHP file?

Comment: Yes, Nginx has URL [rewrite features](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). Look for _The rewrite Directive_

Comment: Can you create a URL like `/property?a=test &b=sell&c= 12536` After that, you can access with a get parameter as `$_GET['a'], $_GET['b'], $_GET['c']`.

Answer (score 2):

Input arguments are defined as `?index=value&anotherIndex=anotherValue` and so forth, for example: `https://example.com/search.php?query=How+to+google&lang=en`

PHP will then have the variables named as the appropriate index (`$_GET['index']` will return you the `value`).

If you'd like to have routes like `example.com/shoes/5/seller` then you'd need to code a custom PHP function which trims the URL and looks for strings and then stores them in an appropriate variable, probably using a regex and `preg_match`. Though, be careful about security as these can  be rather vulnerable to things like SQL injections and server-side code execution vulnerabilities.